# Enter key do not close jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery dialog box when I click on Ok jquery window close but when I hit enter jquery window close and again reopen. How to handle if someone hit enter to close jquery dialog box.

Please is my code.

```
function showDialog(strText,actionUrl,object){
  $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
  var w = screen.availWidth;
  var h = screen.availHeight;
  var leftPos = (w-350)/1.5, topPos = (h-170)/1.5;

  document.getElementById("validateMsg").innerHTML="<p align='center' style='font-size: 13px;'>"+strText+"</p>";

  $("#validateMsg" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width:350,
    height:170,
    title:"Message",
    dialogClass: "noclose",
    buttons: {
      "Ok": function() {
        // on enter control comes here but window close and re open again but if I click on ok then window close 
        $("#validateMsg").dialog( "close" );
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        $("#validateMsg").dialog('destroy').empty();
        if(actionUrl.length != 0){
        location.href=actionUrl;
      }

      if(object.length != 0){
      object.focus(); 
    }
  }
}

});

     $('body').on('keydown', '#validateMsg', '', function (e) {
                     if (e.keyCode == "13") {
                         $(this).dialog('close');
                     }
                 });

//$.scrollTo(0, 0);

$("#validateMsg").dialog('open');


//   return false;
}
```

// edited
if I remove below code then enter is working but I want the focus back on input text

```
 if(actionUrl.length != 0){
        location.href=actionUrl;
      }

      if(object.length != 0){
      object.focus(); 
    }
```

How to close window on enter key in above code.

Regards,Pise

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @CodingAnt Sorry I am new to jquery and have seen jsfiddle website where we can test our code but why do you mean by provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$(function () {
     $('body').on('keydown', '#validateMsg', '', function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == "13") {
             $(this).dialog('close');
         }
     });
 });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NKJDZ/1/)**

Comment: I get following error TypeError: $(...).on is not a function and my code is ` $( document ).ready(function() {
$('body').on('keydown', '#validateMsg', '', function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == "13") {
$(this).dialog('close');
}
});
}); `

Comment: I am getting same error and I have updated the code. Please see updated code. TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: object.focus(); call the keyup function and in turn it again calls the jquery dialog box and it goes into indefinite loop. So now I have to prevent keyup function on focus() and then my problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works:

```
$('.my-dialog').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
    $('.my-dialog').dialog("close");
  }
});
```